# highcharts - drilldown: does not workn with AJAX

Tags: ajax, highcharts, drilldown

I have a chart below that does not work with AJAX request.

```
function ajaxGraficoBarraUnidade() {
        var strSeries = "";
        var strDrilldown = "";
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            data: window.formData + '&strMundo=' + "<?php echo ($strMundo); ?>" + '&strGraph=Unidade',
            dataType: "json",
            url: "ajaxBlitzCarregamentoGrafico.php",
            beforeSend: function () {
            },
            success: function (strRetorno) {
                strSeries = strRetorno.geos;
                strDrilldown = strRetorno.unidades;
                carregaGraficoBarraUnidade(strSeries, strDrilldown);
            },
            error: function (txt) {

            }
        });
    }


    function carregaGraficoBarraUnidade(strSeries, strDrilldown) {

        $('#divGraficoBarraUnidade').highcharts({
            chart: {
                type: 'column'
            },
            title: {
                text: 'Browser market shares. January, 2015 to May, 2015'
            },
            subtitle: {
                text: 'Click the columns to view versions. Source: <a href="http://netmarketshare.com">netmarketshare.com</a>.'
            },
            xAxis: {
                type: 'category'
            },
            yAxis: {
                title: {
                    text: 'Total percent market share'
                }

            },
            legend: {
                enabled: false
            },
            plotOptions: {
                series: {
                    borderWidth: 0,
                    dataLabels: {
                        enabled: true,
                        format: '{point.y:.1f}%'
                    }
                }
            },

            tooltip: {
                headerFormat: '<span style="font-size:11px">{series.name}</span><br>',
                pointFormat: '<span style="color:{point.color}">{point.name}</span>: <b>{point.y:.2f}%</b> of total<br/>'
            },

            series: strSeries,
            drilldown: {
                series: strDrilldown
            }
        });
    </code>
```

I have a return equal to ajax below:

```
{'geos':[{'name': 'Regionais','data': [{'name':'Geo CO','y':1.59,'drilldown':'Geo CO'},{'name':'Geo MG/ES','y':4.41,'drilldown':'Geo MG/ES'},{'name':'Geo NE','y':3.35,'drilldown':'Geo NE'},{'name':'Geo NO','y':1.96,'drilldown':'Geo NO'},{'name':'Geo PR/SPI','y':0.10,'drilldown':'Geo PR/SPI'},{'name':'Geo RJ','y':1.81,'drilldown':'Geo RJ'},{'name':'Geo RS/SC','y':0.75,'drilldown':'Geo RS/SC'},{'name':'Geo SPC','y':0.33,'drilldown':'Geo SPC'}]}], 'unidades':[{'name':'Geo CO','id':'Geo CO','data': [['CDC Araguaina',1.30],['CDC Catalao',0.01],['CDC Formosa',4.70],['CDC Porto Velho',0.29],['CDC Rio Branco',0.00],['CDC Rio Verde',0.12],['CDC Rondonopolis',5.15],['CDC Tangara',0.51],['CDD Brasilia',0.06],['CDD Brasilia Int',2.67],['CDD Caceres',0.05],['CDD Campo Gde',0.00],['CDD Cuiaba Int',0.03],['CDD Goiania Int',0.00],['CDD Itumbiara',38.19],['CDD Manaus',0.43]]},{'name':'Geo MG/ES','id':'Geo MG/ES','data': [['CDD Alfenas',0.02],['CDD Cachoeiro',0.28],['CDD Ipatinga',0.03],['CDD João Monlevade DDC',0.00],['CDD Minas Int',0.77],['CDD Poços de Caldas',0.91],['CDD Pouso Alegre',0.17],['CDD Uberaba',0.08],['CDD Uberlandia',0.07],['CDD Vitoria',25.62],['CDL AS Minas',0.01],['CDL Santa Luzia',2.70]]},{'name':'Geo NE','id':'Geo NE','data': [['CDC Arapiraca',0.12],['CDC Lapa',0.32],['CDD Aracaju',0.05],['CDD Caruaru',8.05],['CDD F. de Santana',0.17],['CDD Guanambi',0.01],['CDD Ilheus',0.03],['CDD Maceio',0.06],['CDD Olinda',0.16],['CDD Rib. Pombal',0.04],['CDD Salvador',0.17],['CDD Vit. da Conquista',0.06],['CDL Cabo',1.33],['CDL Jequie',0.06]]},{'name':'Geo NO','id':'Geo NO','data': [['CDD Aracati',0.02],['CDD Balsas',0.08],['CDD Belem',0.02],['CDD Campina Grande',0.03],['CDD Fortaleza',0.03],['CDD Imperatriz',0.02],['CDD Joao Pessoa Int',5.86],['CDD Maranhao Int ',12.72],['CDD Natal Int',0.02],['CDD Sul Maranhão',0.03],['CDL Ceara',0.37]]},{'name':'Geo PR/SPI','id':'Geo PR/SPI','data': [['CDC Beltrao',0.00],['CDD Agudos Int',0.12],['CDD Araçatuba',0.07],['CDD Araraquara',0.02],['CDD Bebedouro',0.09],['CDD Curitiba',0.00],['CDD Jaú',3.19],['CDD Londrina',0.00],['CDD Mogi Mirim',0.04],['CDD Ponta Grossa',0.37],['CDD Presidente Prudente',0.05],['CDD Rib. Preto',0.04],['CDL Paranagua',0.02]]},{'name':'Geo RJ','id':'Geo RJ','data': [['CDD Campos',1.18],['CDD Jacarepagua',1.65],['CDD Niteroi',0.02],['CDD Nova Friburgo',0.01],['CDD Nova Iguacu',0.02],['CDD Petropolis',0.00],['CDD RJ Campo Gde Int',3.77],['CDD S. Cristovao',0.81],['CDL Itaperuna',0.14]]},{'name':'Geo RS/SC','id':'Geo RS/SC','data': [['CDD Blumenau',0.07],['CDD Camboriu',0.11],['CDD Caxias do Sul',0.07],['CDD Florianopolis',0.12],['CDD Pelotas',0.04],['CDD Porto Alegre',1.06],['CDD S. Cruz Sul',0.02],['CDD Santa Maria',0.45],['CDD Sapucaia Int',2.66]]},{'name':'Geo SPC','id':'Geo SPC','data': [['CDD Campinas',0.12],['CDD Diadema',0.72],['CDD Guarulhos',0.23],['CDD Jundiai',1.04],['CDD Litoral SP',0.05],['CDD Mooca',1.05],['CDD Norte',0.10],['CDD Oeste',0.04],['CDD Praia Grande',0.06],['CDD São José dos Campos',0.54],['CDD Sul SP',0.00],['CDD Taubaté',0.82],['CDD Votorantin',0.77]]}]}
```

It does not recognize the values passed in SERIES. I do not think the error. Does anyone know what might be happening? Tanks!

Comment: I have used your code and I think it is working fine in my case. Here you can find code used for making chart: http://pastebin.com/YXNuzuAE And here php file I have used: http://pastebin.com/vkKrbjzG

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What might be happening is your data is getting loaded after the chart is created, so I've changed the format to be as shown in the Highcharts documentation, but tried not to change to much otherwise.

[Highcharts documentation on working with data](http://www.highcharts.com/docs/working-with-data/custom-preprocessing#3)

[See a plunkr demo with your chart working with available data](http://embed.plnkr.co/BWiMbP8cpTVn4xRJ59oF/)

The data is hosted on myjson.com as JSON, so I changed the POST to a GET request.

Here is the key HTML code:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.0.0.min.js" integrity="sha256-JmvOoLtYsmqlsWxa7mDSLMwa6dZ9rrIdtrrVYRnDRH0=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>

<div id="divGraficoBarraUnidade" style="width:100%; height:400px;"></div>
```

This is the Javascript / jQuery code:

```
$(function () {
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var options = {
            chart: {
                renderTo: 'divGraficoBarraUnidade',
                type: 'column'
            },
            title: {
                text: 'Browser market shares. January, 2015 to May, 2015'
            },
            subtitle: {
                text: 'Click the columns to view versions. Source: <a href="http://netmarketshare.com">netmarketshare.com</a>.'
            },
            xAxis: {
                type: 'category'
            },
            yAxis: {
                title: {
                    text: 'Total percent market share'
                }
            },
            legend: {
                enabled: false
            },
            plotOptions: {
                series: {
                    borderWidth: 0,
                    dataLabels: {
                        enabled: true,
                        format: '{point.y:.1f}%'
                    }
                }
            },
            tooltip: {
                headerFormat: '<span style="font-size:11px">{series.name}</span><br>',
                pointFormat: '<span style="color:{point.color}">{point.name}</span>: <b>{point.y:.2f}%</b> of total<br/>'
            },
            series: {},
            drilldown: {
                series: {}
            }
        };

        function ajaxGraficoBarraUnidade() {
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                data: window.formData + '&strMundo=' + "<?php echo ($strMundo); ?>" + '&strGraph=Unidade',
                dataType: "json",
                url: "https://api.myjson.com/bins/42c59",
                beforeSend: function () {
                },
                success: function (strRetorno) {
                    options.series = strRetorno.geos;
                    options.drilldown.series = strRetorno.unidades;
                    var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
                    console.log('options', options)
                },
                error: function (txt) {
                    // Report errors here...
                }
            });
        }
        ajaxGraficoBarraUnidade();
    });
});
```